# Image matching and transformation

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks

I hope this picture can help me to be clearer. 
The triangles represent some values of an image (EDITED: positions). 
The same for the circles, but from a different image. 
Some values matches, some others not, as you can see (I know, I am not good at drawing!). 
I would like to ask you if there is a way to find the values that match (i.e. transform triangles/circles in values again) and list the corresponding values from one of the two images.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: "The triangles represent some values of an image" - do you mean positions? or pixel values at the indicated positions?

Comment: Yes, I mean positions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if the features are of similar size and non-overlapping. For illustration, I made this image with red and green spots. The co-localized spots are almost, but not exactly, coincident. (Something resembling red and green channels from a DNA microarray, maybe.)

[image]

Here are the red and green channels:

```
{r, g} = ColorSeparate[img][[1 ;; 2]]
```

[image]

Spots can be automatically detected with [`MorphologicalComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalComponents.html). (If there is background signal or noise amongst the real features, some more work would need to be done to select the authentic features.)

```
spots = MorphologicalComponents /@ {r, g};
```

[`ComponentMeasurements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) can then be used to get the centroid of each spot.

```
centroids = ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"][[All, 2]] & /@ spots;
```

Check that spot detection is working:

```
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[centroids[[1]]], Green, 
  Point[centroids[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

Next, we can decide on some tolerance within which spots will be called co-localized. For example, I used the mean radius of the spots.

```
tolerance = 
 Mean[Flatten[ComponentMeasurements[#, "EquivalentDiskRadius"] & /@ spots][[All, 2]]];
```

The coordinates of the green spots that co-localize with red spots are then

```
coincidentspots = 
 Select[Table[
            {gcentroid, EuclideanDistance[Nearest[centroids[[1]], gcentroid][[1]], gcentroid]},    
            {gcentroid, centroids[[2]]}], 
       #[[2]] < tolerance &][[All, 1]]

 (* {{176.5, 467.5}, {403.5, 463.5}, {63.4845, 459.015}, {166., 381.5}, {414.485, 370.015}, {73., 281.}, {166., 276.}, {292., 198.5}, {78., 82.5}, {292., 82.5}, {427., 73.5}} *)
```

For illustration:

```
Show[r, Graphics[{Green, PointSize[Large], Point[coincidentspots]}]]
```

[image]